# How to remove strings present in a list from a column in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "name": [
            "Hello Kitty",
            "Hello Puppy",
            "It is an Helloexample",
            "for stackoverflow",
            "Hello World",
        ],
    }
)
```

which looks like:

```
   ID               name
0   1        Hello Kitty
1   2        Hello Puppy
2   3   It is an Helloexample
3   4  for stackoverflow
4   5        Hello World
```

I have a list of strings `To_remove_list`

```
To_remove_lst = ["Hello", "for", "an", "It"]
```

I need to remove all the strings present in the list from the column `name` of `df`. How can I do this in pandas ?

My expected answer is:

```
   ID               name
0   1              Kitty
1   2              Puppy
2   3              is example
3   4              stackoverflow
4   5              World
```

Comment: Does `to_remove_lst` contain full words or can it contain substrings?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: It can be a substring

Comment: I'll add the expected output in question

Comment: You may want to state that up front or else 90% of the answers here will be useless to you.

Comment: I hope you took a look at all the answers and actually tested them out on your data instead of accepting based on the number of votes (sometimes that can be misleading).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think need [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) if want remove also substrings:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('|'.join(To_remove_lst), '')
```

If possible some regex characters:

```
import re
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('|'.join(map(re.escape, To_remove_lst)), '')

print (df)
   ID            name
0   1           Kitty
1   2           Puppy
2   3     is  example
3   4   stackoverflow
4   5           World
```

But if want remove only words use nested list comprehension:

```
df['name'] = [' '.join([y for y in x.split() if y not in To_remove_lst]) for x in df['name']]
```

Comment: What if there are regex characters in my strings I want to remove as well?

Comment: You always provide a variety of answers/options in all your posts +1!

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend `re.sub` in a list comprehension for speed.

```
import re
p = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, To_remove_lst)))
df['name'] = [p.sub('', text) for text in df['name']] 

print (df)
   ID            name
0   1           Kitty
1   2           Puppy
2   3     is  example
3   4   stackoverflow
4   5           World
```

List comprehensions are implemented in C and operate in C speed. I highly recommend list comprehensions when working with string and regex data over pandas `str` functions for the time-being because the API is a bit slow.

The use of `map(re.escape, To_remove_lst)` is to escape any possible regex metacharacters which are meant to be treated literally during replacement.

The pattern is precompiled before calling `regex.sub` to reduce the overhead of compilation at each iteration.

I've also let it slide but please use PEP-8 compliant variable names "to_remove_lst" (lower-snake case).

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)
%timeit df['name'].str.replace('|'.join(To_remove_lst), '')
%timeit [p.sub('', text) for text in df['name']] 

100 ms ± 5.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
60 ms ± 3.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: does the re.escape replace metacharacters if they are contained in my string?  I don't know what you mean by "escape" and have looked at the documentation.  Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: @acodejdatam If your string contains any [metacharacters](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#matching-characters) that you want to be treated literally (instead of being parsed as metacharacters by the regex engine), then that's when you'd want `re.escape` here. There's a good explanation in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a for loop for each element and then use str.replace

```
for WORD in To_remove_lst:
    df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(WORD, '')
```

Output:

```
   ID            name
0   1           Kitty
1   2           Puppy
2   3     is  example
3   4   stackoverflow
4   5           World
```